# Alan AI does't install in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

```
❯ sudo npm i @alan-ai/alan-sdk-react-native --save


> @alan-ai/alan-sdk-react-native@1.0.7 postinstall /Users/codrain/Desktop/React Native/alanNews/node_modules/@alan-ai/alan-sdk-react-native
> cp AlanSDK.js $INIT_CWD && cp AlanButton.js $INIT_CWD && cp AlanText.js $INIT_CWD

usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 64
npm ERR! @alan-ai/alan-sdk-react-native@1.0.7 postinstall: `cp AlanSDK.js $INIT_CWD && cp AlanButton.js $INIT_CWD && cp AlanText.js $INIT_CWD`
npm ERR! Exit status 64
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @alan-ai/alan-sdk-react-native@1.0.7 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/codrain/.npm/_logs/2021-01-16T16_24_42_297Z-debug.log
npm ERR!     /Users/codrain/.npm/_logs/2021-01-16T16_24_42_297Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried into my project and got the same error, so the problem should come from the package itself and not from you.

Maybe try to open an issue [here](https://github.com/alan-ai/alan-sdk-reactnative/issues)

Or find another package because this one doesn't seem to be updated often.